# NULL value is saving in database instead of user submitted info

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am facing following problem

My problem

Problem i m facing is that whenever I submit the form after filling firstname lastname and phone, then everything going well except one thing that in my MYSQL database data is save as firstname: NULL lastname:NULL And phone:NULL instead of saving the data which i had enter.

I have a angularjs form in which is there fields like firstname lastname and phone.on submit it goes to submitContact() in controller:

submit.js:

```
 var addnew = angular.module('addnew',[]);

 // create angular controller
 addnew.controller('addContactController',            
 function($scope,$location,$window,$http) {


// function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
$scope.submitContact = function() {

    $scope.addnew = {firstname:'', lastname:'',phone:''};

        $scope.addnew.firstname=$scope.firstname;
        $scope.addnew.lastname=$scope.lastname;
        $scope.addnew.phone=$scope.phone;


         $http.get("http://localhost:8000/index.php/user/addnew",{"firstname": $scope.firstname, "phone": $scope.phone, "lastname": $scope.lastname})
        .then(function mysuccess(response) {
            $scope.mycard = response.data;
            $scope.statuscode = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statustext;
            $window.alert(JSON.stringify(response));
             console.log(response.data);
           });

};
```

});

http://localhost:8000/index.php/user/addnew this links to my laravel through routes.

my route.php:

```
 Route::get('/user/addnew', 'usercontroller@store');
```

my usercontroller.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

  //contacts::create(Request::all());
  $user = new contacts;// contacts is my table name and my database is defined in .env file
  $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
  $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
  $user->phone = Input::get('phone');
  $user->save();
 //I Used print_r to see that weather my submitted data is coming in $user or not:
  print_r($user);

    echo "saved";
}
```

my contact.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class contacts extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['firstname','lastname','phone'];
}

?>
```

Now, My problem

when i print_r  $user then i got the error as my array is NOT catching my submitted data 
print_r ($user) output in console window:

```
[fillable:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => firstname
        [1] => lastname
        [2] => phone
    )

[connection:protected] => 
[table:protected] => 
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[keyType:protected] => int
[perPage:protected] => 15
[incrementing] => 1
[timestamps] => 1
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => 
        [lastname] => 
        [phone] => 
        [updated_at] => 2016-10-07 03:46:34
        [created_at] => 2016-10-07 03:46:34
        [id] => 38
    )

[original:protected] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => 
        [lastname] => 
        [phone] => 
        [updated_at] => 2016-10-07 03:46:34
        [created_at] => 2016-10-07 03:46:34
        [id] => 38
    )
```

I want to know where I m making mistake and how can I correct that mistake.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the output of dd($request->all());

Comment: Ya tried this too but thing is, it saving only Null as value of all field in contacts table of my database.

Comment: Are you getting request response?, When you do dd($request->all()), you can see the request in your browser console.

Comment: Please tell us what the response to dd($request->all()); is

Comment: I am getting empty array when i return the $request and in console log window it showing all internal script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I achived this by using `$request->input('firstname');` `$request->input('firstname');` `$request->input('firstname');`, since, it was JSON thats why. Else, If I had been using Laravel blade file then I could have done it by above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = new Contact();
```

Instead of this:

```
$user = new contacts;
```

Also, change class name to `class Contact extends Model` and a filename to a `Contact.php`.

Alternatively, since you're using `$fillable` you can create new row:

```
Contact::create($request->all());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working..I also tried Contact::create($request->all()); yet its saving only NULL as value in database

Comment: Change class name and filename. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use POST instead of GET.

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8000/index.php/user/addnew",{"firstname": $scope.firstname, "phone": $scope.phone, "lastname": $scope.lastname})
    .then(function mysuccess(response) {
        $scope.mycard = response.data;
        $scope.statuscode = response.status;
        $scope.statustext = response.statustext;
        $window.alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         console.log(response.data);
       });
```

And

```
Route::post('/user/addnew', 'usercontroller@store');
```

And I noticed that you are posting to `/index.php/user/addnew`
And your route is `'/user/addnew'`
`'/index.php/user/addnew'` and `'/user/addnew'` are different.
try posting to `localhost:8000/user/addnew` instead

To explain:

`/user/addnew` always refer to `host:port/user/addnew`

While `user/addnew` will just concatenate it to your current url

for example if you're currently at: `localhost:8000/users/1`

Clicking a link to `user/addnew` will bring you to `localhost:8000/users/1/user/addnew` while a link to `/user/addnew` will bring you to `localhost:8000/user/addnew`

EDIT:

Is this redundant?

```
$scope.addnew.firstname=$scope.firstname;
$scope.addnew.lastname=$scope.lastname;
$scope.addnew.phone=$scope.phone;
```

What you were sending is this:

```
{"firstname": $scope.firstname, "phone": $scope.phone, "lastname": $scope.lastname}
```

I think you can send this instead:

`$scope.addnew`

and again, you should use **POST**, not *GET*.

did you already update your http request to post? did you update the url?

Comment: In case you didn't understand my explanation xD: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Comment: It will be great if you could explain me how to send JSON data from angularjs side and how to get the same data into laravel side so that it can be saved in mysql table. Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: I've updated my answer, it could be that your request is working, but i think that your $request is NULL is because it is a GET request. GET requests are meant for retrieving data, not inputting data. though, my second guess is that, your $scope.firstname, $scope.phone and $scope.lastname are empty. try console.log($scope.addnew) after setting its attributes. That way we can see if it really has data in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pointing my mistake..I had seen another thing that whatever I m sending json data to Laravel..laravel unable to get that json that and that's why its giving null as value in table..How can I retrieve the json data in laravel controller..??

Comment: you can do $request->get('firstname'), and so on. :)

Comment: if you dd($request->all()); and it returns NULL or NULL array. Then the problem is with the front-end. try logging on both the laravel and angular side, to see where the bug is taking place.